# Using php to update mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, exception, syntax-error

I'm very new at coding/programming, therefore solving problems is not easy for me at all. I have to make a php page that should let me display the mysql table, let me update the values and insert new ones.

Currently I got stuck with making the update button, the error says "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/madisu/public_html/webprog1/kodutoo_toovoog/kodutoo_3.php on line 21".

And I think it's the code which controls whether the "update" button works?

```
if(isSet($_POST['update'])) {
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE proov SET id='$_POST[id]', name='$_POST[name]', email='$_POST[email]', phone='$_POST[phone]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";
    mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc)
}
```

Comment: @madis121: Please do read about **SQL injection** and other/similar vulnerabilities.

Comment: you have a missing semi-colon on the mysql_query() line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $hidden = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hidden']);

    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE proov SET id='$id', name='$name', email='$email', phone='$phone' WHERE id='$hidden'";
    mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc);
}
```

you missed a semicolon...

note: it's not a good idea to use unsanitized POST values for db queries.

note 2: why don't you use Adminer or PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Oh yes! Silly me haha. Thanks for all the fast replies! And I don't really know, I probably should use something better than my uni server. Once again, thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you note that inserting unescaped $_POST data into a query us bad, why don't you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing semi colon

```
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with below code

```
if(isSet($_POST['update'])) {
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE proov SET id='".$_POST['id']."', name='".$_POST['name']."', email='".$_POST['email']."', phone='".$_POST['phone']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['hidden']."'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Semicolon missing after the below line.

```
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc)
```

Corrected below.

```
if(isSet($_POST['update'])) {
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE proov SET id='$_POST[id]', name='$_POST[name]', email='$_POST[email]', phone='$_POST[phone]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'";

mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc);  //CORRECTED

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with below code

```html
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE proov SET id='".$_POST['id']."', name='".$_POST['name']."', email='".$_POST['email']."', phone='".$_POST['phone']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['hidden'];
    mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (isSet($_POST['update'])) {
  $errors = true;
  // Check if the values are set
  if (isset($_POST['id'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['hidden']))
    $errors = false;

  if (!$errors) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $hidden = $_POST['hidden'];

    $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE proov SET id='$id', name='$name', email='$email', phone='$phone' WHERE id = '$hidden'";
    mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $dbc);
  } else {
    echo "An error occurred.  One or more of the post values were not set.";
    trigger_error(var_dump($_POST['update']), E_USER_WARNING);
  }
}
```

It's just a simple check to give you an idea.